# why adding razorformat breaks web services in servicestack latest 3.9.45.0

Tags: razor, http-status-code-404, servicestack

I am breaking my head today why after upgrading to latest servicestack and servicestack.razor my routing in web services stops working. So I did the following test.

1. created a new empty web project in vs.net 2012
2. added web.config file from rockstar
3. added servicestack and razor through nuget
4. added apphost and global.asa
5. in my configure() i did not add anything - no plugins.
6. added a simple echoservice with route specified

at this point point all works fine, i click the routed url and get my echo result back

1. added the line to config to add RazorFormat plugin

Now the route does not work, I am getting 404 (file not found) after return from the service with echo data. I can create a view for that service and then all fine, but what happened to default display?

Thanks
Mark

I tried to do the same with servicestack out of the box example and get the same result

1. Took a sample from servicestack – RootPath40 + Common and included them in separate solution
2. Compiled and it works
3. Current version of servicestack used by example is 3.9.11.0
4. Ran the following to update servicestack and install razor on both projects in the solution
   so i get latest 3.9.45

   install-package servicestack

   install-package servicestack.razor
5. Tested – works fine!!!. I am testing specifically Hello service using the route Hello -> 
   localhost/RootPath40/hello
6. 

Added 1 line to Global.asax.cs – Configure function

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
        {
            container.Register(new TodoRepository());
            **Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat());**
       }
```

1. Now the route hello do not work anymore because I get error 404 not found.

I am using vs.net 2012 and windows 8

I am sure I am missing something very trivial, anyone knows...

Thanks

After struggling a little more I see that if I add reference to **System.Web.Razor.Unofficial.dll** then razor pages are served but routed web services stop working, the minute I remove the reference the web service routing urls are fine but razor pages are not served.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Finally i figured out the problem.
The new version of servicestack (3.9.45.0) appears to have a bug in IF condition.

In HtmlFormat.cs

```
public void SerializeToStream(IRequestContext requestContext, object response, IHttpResponse httpRes)
        {
            var httpReq = requestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>();
            if (httpReq != null && AppHost.ViewEngines.Any(x => x.ProcessRequest(httpReq, httpRes, response))) return;
            ...
            ...
```

The "NOT" ! (exclamation mark) is missing, but it should only return if none of the ViewEngines executed request. I added the NOT and walla, all works.

```
  if (httpReq != null && **!**AppHost.ViewEngines.Any(x => x.ProcessRequest(httpReq, httpRes, response))) return;
```

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug with the new Razor support that was [identified in this issue](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/issues/682) and fixed in v3.9.46+ of [ServiceStack.Razor](https://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Razor/).