# Upgrading to latest Servicestack from old Razor version has broken services

Tags: razor, servicestack, razor-2

I have been having an issue with versions of ServiceStack that use the new Razor (any version after 3.9.44).

With 3.9.43 all runs as expected but when I use any commit version after the Razor update my cshtml pages dont seem to compile anymore.

Through debugging it I can see that it finds all the cshtml pages however it never gets to the point of compiling them.

I have tried using razor rockstarts page changing the references to my local copy of servicestack to eliminate any errors with the local copy and rockstars runs fine, I have also double checked rockstars agains my services and cshtml pages to see if there are any obvious changes that need to be done but cant see anything.

I have also tried directly copying all the config files from rockstars but that doesn't make any difference.

Currently running this on a local machine running Mono 2.10.11

Is there any obvious changes that need to be done when upgrading from the old servicestack versions to new ones?

I also thought that maybe razor just doesn't inform you if a compilation succeeded anymore and so tried to just access the site/service directly, however I get the following from the output console:

> ERROR: Error occured while Processing Request: [HttpCompileException] External exception, Exception: External exception
>
> INFO: Failed to write error to response: {0}, Exception: The object was used after being disposed.
>
> ERROR: Error occured while Processing Request: External exception, Exception: External exception

Noting this post: [why adding razorformat breaks web services in servicestack latest 3.9.45.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618526/why-adding-razorformat-breaks-web-services-in-servicestack-latest-3-9-45-0)

I tried removing the RazorFormat plugin from the AppHost.cs file

Which  then actually produces a page when accessing the website:

> Snapshot of LoginRequest generated by ServiceStack on 12/07/2013 09:53:24
>
> view json datasource from original url: localhost:1338/Login? in other formats: json xml csv jsv
>
> Error Message
>
> Route After

Viewing it as direct json gives:

```
{"ErrorMessage":"","RouteAfter":""}
```

Comment: Please provide some more code details. https://github.com/kunjee17/ServiceStackHeroku here is the demo I created for F#. It is working great even with Razor engine.